# A simple prolog program in rule

Tags: prolog

```
fooA(1,1).
fooA(N,X) :-
    M is N-1,
    fooA(M,Y),
    X is 3*Y+1.
```

If I run `fooA(3,X)`， then `X is 13`

Why does `fooA(5,X)` results in `X is 10` ??

The code should work with the following rules:

> 1. `fooA(1,1)` is fact
> 2. If `M is N-1` and `fooA(M,Y)` and `X is 3*Y+1` then `fooA(N,X)` is `true`

So the `fooA(5,X)` solution is:

```
25
```

but it is not, my program generates `10`.

Can someone explain the program procedure and point out my errors.

Comment: How did you get 10? When I tried `fooA(5, X)` I got `X = 121`, then after pressing `;` it overflowed the stack (you should have `N > 1` as a condition in your second clause).

Comment: maybe the question have wrong and lost some code
I will confirm this question from my teacher  THX